# How to run some testcases in parallel and some in serial manner in java junit test class?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, testing, junit

I have a situation where some of the testclasses in my test suite needs to be run in sequential way and others in parallel way.

Basically, we are running the test cases using maven

```
mvn -DreuseForks=false clean install
```

The property `-DreuseForks=false` ensures that the testcases are run in parallel and that is what we want so the entire suite is efficient. But some test classes are there which we dont want to run in parallel.
Is there any way I can achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

JUnit encourages tests to be independent of each other. 
That said, if you really do need to specify the order in which tests are run, you can try using @FixMethodOrder.   https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/FixMethodOrder.html

Comment: `JUnit encourages tests to be independent of each other.` it's not a JUnit specific recommendation. This is an automated testing rule of thumb.